# My org-mode has different size text at different level

Tags: org-mode, themes, text-properties

Actually what happened was this.

I was looking for a good theme for my emacs. In the process I have changed many themes. I don't know which theme caused this but now my org-mode has different size text at each level.

I don't like this. They look very uneven. Can you please tell me how to undo this?[image: A screenshot of my org-mode text]

Comment: My course of action would be as follows: move the point to a heading, `M-x describe-face` should offer the face under point. For example `org-level-2`, then look in my init file for something that changes it.

Comment: I will try that for sure.

Comment: @wvxvw Shouldn't that be `org-level-1`?  From the screenshot only the top level headline seems to be larger, where as all the others are equal in size.

Comment: @suvayu I wouldn't know :) it could've make the inner headings smaller too.

Comment: You can use `M-x customize-themes` to check what theme you're using and to disable it or change to another theme.

Comment: @xuchunyang I tried that. I think the theme which changed the faces wouldn't undo them when we disable it.

Comment: Is there a way by which I could restore the font sizes to the way they looked initially?

Comment: @SampathSurineni It should be easy to find out which theme caused the problem: don't load any theme in your init.el or custom.el and restart Emacs, then `M-x customize-themes` to enable/disable all theme one by one.  I think It should be considered as a bug of that theme, you should suggest the theme author to fix it and don't use it for now.

Comment: @xuchunyang Thanks for the suggestion. I'll do that and let you know the result.

Comment: @xuchunyang just found out what was causing the problem. solarized-light theme is the one

Comment: @xuchunyang can you include your last comment an answer. I would accept it as it solved my problem.

Comment: `(setq solarized-scale-org-headlines nil)` to disable headlines scaling in solarized theme.

Comment: @SampathSurineni You can answer your own question and accept it, since  now you know the full answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem was with the current theme I am using which was solarized theme. This is the link to the theme https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs. I figured out the problem by un-applying the theme through `customize-theme`. If you are using the same theme you can solve this problem by including `(setq solarized-scale-org-headlines nil)` in your `init` file .